# ec2 describe-account-attributes - Is the result for the entire account or for regions within an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What does the output of `ec2 describe-account-attributes` exactly represent?
I see this object in there,

```
{
            "AttributeName": "max-instances",
            "AttributeValues": [
                {
                    "AttributeValue": "20"
                }
            ]
        }
```

1. Is `"AttributeValue": "20"` for the entire account cumulatively or for every region separately?
2. Also, if I request for the limit to be increased does the increased limit apply to all the regions or do I have to specify the region?
3. I read somewhere that the limits apply to specific instance types separately which confuses me even more about the output of this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon EC2 limits are **per region** within the account.

When requesting a limit increase, you will need to specify the region.

I have even seen some organizations request a *limit decrease*. For example, if they do not wish to run any resources in a particular region, they changed the limit to zero in that region.

There is a limit on the **total number of concurrently-running Amazon EC2 instances in the region**, and there are also **limits on the specific instance types**.

You can **view the limits in the Amazon EC2 management console** by clicking **Limits** in the left navigation pane.

Comment: Thanks. 'limit decrease' -- that's interesting

Answer (score 0):

This is the value for whichever region you sent the query to.

If you didn't specify, then it's the one you selected as default when configuring aws-cli.  You can also use `aws ec2 describe-availability-zones` to confirm which region it is.

This value is derived from the largest value of any single type of instance you're allowed to run in that region -- it's not a separate limit that you need to ask to be increased.

Limits are based on instance type, in each region, and you can view the more detailed limits [in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html).  The detailed limits are not accessible from the API.

When you request a limit increase, you're essentially asking AWS to review the available capacity of a specific type of hardware in a specific region and approve (or deny) your request based on that availability (and possibly other aspects of your described use case and account history).  The request you make is not only regional, but also for a specific type of instance... but you will typically find that they will increase the limit for all or several instance types in the family -- if you ask for more t2.micro, you may automatically get the increased limit for t2.nano and t2.small as well (for example), allowing you to scale the machines up or down within the t2 family without needing to make more requests for limit increases.